# Redirecting all trafic within a folder to a login.php file in another folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

How do I redirect all traffic from one folder to a file in another folder (eg. https://www.example.com/office/****** to https://www.example.com/folder/login.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below with mod_rewrite inside your folder where requests are coming,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.example.com/folder/login.php [R=301]
```

or with mod_alias on

```
Redirect / https://www.example.com/folder/login.php
```